# jQuery Autocomplete slow with over 120,000 values in array. Advice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

So a few things are happening to make the searching slow. Firstly, it's a list of over 120,000 values. Secondly, while I'm searching I'm also checking for accents and trying to allow accents to not tarnish the users search.

Here are my settings for the autocomplete:

```
lookup: footballers,
lookupLimit: 5,
minChars: 3,
delay: 100,
autoSelectFirst: true,
lookupFilter: _autocompleteLookup,
formatResult: _autocompleteFormatResult,
```

How I'm handling the checking for accents:

```
var _formatRegexp = function(q) {
    q = q.replace(/e/i,'[eéèêëEÉÈÊË]');
    q = q.replace(/a/i,'[aáàâäåæAÀÁÂÃÄÅÆ]');
    q = q.replace(/c/i,'[cçC]');
    q = q.replace(/i/i,'[iïîíìIÌÍÎÏ]');
    q = q.replace(/o/i,'[oôöœøOÒÓÔÕØÖ]');
    q = q.replace(/u/i,'[uüûúùUÜÛÙÚ]');
    q = q.replace(/y/i,'[yYÿýÝŸ]');
    q = q.replace(/z/i,'[zžZYŽ]');
    q = q.replace(/s/i,'[ŠšsS]');
    q = q.replace(/n/i,'[nNñÑ]');
    return q;
}

var _autocompleteLookup = function (suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
        var pattern = '(\\b|^)('+$.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase)+')';
        pattern = _formatRegexp(pattern);
        var matcher = new RegExp(pattern);
        var ret = suggestion.value.toLowerCase().match(matcher);
        return ret;
};

var _autocompleteFormatResult = function (suggestion, currentValue) {
        var pattern = '(\\b|^)('+$.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(currentValue)+')';
        pattern = _formatRegexp(pattern);
        return suggestion.value.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'gi'), '<strong>$1$2<\/strong>');
};
```

and here is my `footballers` array.

```
var footballers = [
{ value: "Nemanja Miletić", data: playerExt+query+ 'Nemanja_Mileti%C4%87' },
{ value: "Miloš Živković", data: playerExt+query+ 'Milo%C5%A1_%C5%BDivkovi%C4%87' },
{ value: "Aleksandr Nikolayevich Vasilyev", data: playerExt+query+ 'Aleksandr_Nikolayevich_Vasilyev' },
//120K more lines..
]
```

Now, is there anything I can do to make the search faster/more responsive? Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I'd prefer to keep this project client side but I'd be up for changing librarys.. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I had the same issue with a large list of static data. I tried a variety of type aheads and autocompletes including jquery ui's. They were all pitifully slow and ended up writing a custom one.

Comment: I think regardless what you do to optimize your custom code checking, with 120k items its going to be slow.

Comment: One suggestion would be to have the auto complete make ajax requests on key typed to return a smaller list from the server. The server can do the lifting and crunching much faster while js client code is working with a much smaller list that updates as key are entered.

Comment: @tellez could you elaborate a bit more? I don't really understand. Thanks.